# Firefox won't load/render custom font

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts, font-face

I have a webpage for a text-shadow generator.I am using the Bootstrap template. I am also using  a custom font. This page is not online just local files. When I use Chrome the custom font will be applied but, in Firefox it won't except it if I upload the page to my website. I use linux for development but the same thing happened when I tried Firefox for Android Beta. Why is this happening?

Here is the image from Firefox:
[image]

And here is how it looks on Chrome or on Firefox when it is uploaded:
[image]

Here is my code:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>CSS3 Text Shadow Generator</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <META NAME="author" CONTENT="kounelios13">
        <META NAME="subject" CONTENT="programming">
        <META NAME="Description" CONTENT="Create text with drop shadows (also known as text-shadow) ">
        <META NAME="Classification" CONTENT="No javascript is needed just pure CSS3">
        <META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="programming,web design,tools,generator">
        <META NAME="Designer" CONTENT="kounelios13">
        <META NAME="distribution" CONTENT="Global">
        <META NAME="country" CONTENT="Greece">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/general.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/navbar-head.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/apps/textshadow.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/apps/sliders.css">

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../../js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../js/prefixfree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../js/apps/textshadow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>
<body class="bg-danger">
<?php include  '../menu.php'; ?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron landing">
        <h1>Text Shadow Generator v1.0 BETA </h1>

    </div>  
    <h1 class="btn btn-info center-block text-center " id="generators">An easy to use text shadow generator</h1>
    You can try your own values in the following form:
    <div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="boxShadowf"><div class="btn btn-success" id="boxSub">Get val</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center">

        <div class="col-md-4">
        <span class="h3">X-axis</span>
            <input type="range" class="slider form-control" id="x" step="0.1" min="-10" max="10" value="0">
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <span class="h3">Y-axis</span>
        <input type="range" class="slider form-control" id="y" step="0.1" min="-10" max="10" value="0">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <span class="h3">Blur</span>
        <input type="range" class="slider form-control" id="blur" step="0.1" min="0" max="10" value="0">
    </div>


        <span class="h2 text-info"  id="text-shadow" contenteditable>All the transformations will be applied here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center h3">



            <div class="col-md-4 text-danger">
                Red
                <input type="range" class="slider rgb" id="red" step="1" min="0" max="255" value="0" style="background:red;">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 text-success">
                Green
                <input type="range" class="slider rgb" id="green" step="1" min="0" max="255" value="0" style="background:green;">

            </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 text-primary">
                Blue
                <input type="range" class="slider rgb" id="blue" step="1" min="0" max="255" value="0" style="background:blue;">
            </div>









    </div>
    <div class="btn btn-warning" id="toggleCode">
        Toggle code

    </div>
    <div class="btn btn-danger" id="resetCode">Reset code</div>
    <h1>Code</h1>
    <div class="code bg-primary text-info " id="code">

        div{
        <p class="text-success bg-info"><span class="standard coded">
                text-shadow:<span class="h-shadow Code">0px</span> <span class="v-shadow Code">0px</span> <span class="blur Code">0px</span> <span class="color"> black</span></span>
        ;</p>

        }
    </div>  

        <div class="btn btn-danger btn-block" id="optimize" >Optimize code</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: '3dumbregular';
    src: url('../../fonts/3dumb/3dumb-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../../fonts/3dumb/3dumb-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../../fonts/3dumb/3dumb-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../../fonts/3dumb/3dumb-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../../fonts/3dumb/3dumb-webfont.svg#3dumbregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
/*body{background:#99afaa;}
*/
div.landing{

font-family: '3dumbregular';
text-align: center;
background: dodgerblue;

}
.landing h1{
    font-style: italic;
    color: red;
}
.generator{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 5em;
    height: 15em;
    width: 15em;
    background: orange;
    border:4px dashed gold;
    border-radius: 8px;

}
.slider{
    background: #aa9df9;
}
.slider:nth-child(1){
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.inset{
    display: none;
}


/* Bρες το .row που ειναι κατευθειαν μετα απο μια ετικετα h1 */
h1 ~.row{
    margin-top: 0.4em;
}

#boxShadowf,#boxSub{
    height: 30px;
}
#boxSub{
    padding: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}

        #inset{
            margin-top: 0.2em;
            margin-bottom: 0.2em;
            width: 10%;
        }
        #code{
            padding: 4px;
        }
```

Comment: Is your Firefox setup to have the browser decide the font styles and defaults or is it set to have each individual page choose? To check, do the following.....

Options->Content->Font&Colors->Advanced->Tick the "Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of my selections above" checkbox...

Let me know if that works

Comment: No still the same!!!

Comment: have you tried giving your font an absolute path rather than a relative one? or even using the Bootstrap CDN for fonts?? just some ideas

Comment: For some strange reason Bootstrap cdn is not working

Comment: if you're using the Bootstrap CDN, JUST use the Bootstrap CDN...take out the other relative paths...that will cause an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox comes with a very strict "file uri origin" (file:///) policy by default: to have it to behave just as other browsers, go to about:config, filter by fileuri and toggle the following preference:

security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy

Set it to false and you should be able to load local font resources across different path levels.